# maxOccurs as unbounded, but don't think of order of elements (xs:all)

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a XSD file in which I have the following situation:

```
<xs:element name='test'>
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:all>
    <xs:element ref='el1' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
    <xs:element ref='el2' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
    <xs:element ref='el3' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
    <xs:element ref='el4' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
    <xs:element ref='el5' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
    <xs:element ref='el6' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
    <xs:element ref='el7' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>    
    <xs:element ref='el8' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded'/>  
   </xs:all>
   <xs:attribute name='attr1' use='optional' type='yesno'/>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

And now the problem is, this isn't working so far, cause I can't have `maxOccurs='unbounded'` within the `all` element. Is there any way to achieve this, e.g. with using `xs:choice`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To preserve the cardinality you want, the only way in XSD 1.0 is to wrap your repeating element with another one, like so:

```
<xs:element name='test'>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element ref='el1' minOccurs='0'/>
            <xs:element ref='el2' minOccurs='0'/>
            <xs:element ref='el3' minOccurs='0'/>
            <xs:element ref='el4' minOccurs='0'/>
            <xs:element ref='el5' minOccurs='0'/>
            <xs:element ref='el6' minOccurs='0'/>
            <xs:element ref='el7' minOccurs='0'/>
            <xs:element ref='el8w' minOccurs='0'/>
        </xs:all>
        <xs:attribute name='attr1' type='yesno'/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="el8w">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="el8" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The (repeating) choice that would mimic the `xs:all` (i.e. allow for interspersed elements with the indicated cardinality) can't enforce the occurrence of individual particles.

Comment: Can I have <xs:element ref='el1' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>? You have written <xs:element ref='el1' minOccurs='0'/>. maxOccurs is missing?!

Comment: The default value of maxOccurs is one. I am used to (and my tooling does it, too) remove superfluous attributes. The same goes for `use` in schema attributes, the default is optional.